# Crash when getting value from shared Userdefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui, crash, widget, nsuserdefaults

I use shared Userdefaults to get values from the parent iOS app into the iOS14 Widget extension.
Everything seems to work, I never seen a crash, not sure if a widget could crash anyways, however, crash analytics say:

Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optical value.

The line is where I get my value from shared Userdefault, so the last line from the following code:

```
struct QuitSmokingWidgetEntryView : View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

let myString:String = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.value(forKey: "myKey") as! String
```

As I said, everything seems to work without crashing, but what am I doing wrong that Xcode crash analytics tells me that many crashes happen in that line? How to fix that?

Thanks for help !

Comment: You are force casting the value `value(forKey: "myKey") as! String`  to string, if `.value` returns nil or returns something which isnt String its bound to crash, why not use `if let` or `guard let` to safe unwrap

Comment: if I put let before Xcode says : Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' If I press fix it looks like ---   if; let myString:String = UserDefaults(suiteName: --- which is not working obviously

Comment: How about `if let myString = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.value(forKey: "myKey") as? String { //your code to use myString here }`

Comment: thanks for answer, Xcode won t let me put if or guard before, I googled - maybe because it is no function?

Comment: It is SwiftIUI, never used it before, really new to it, it s a struct, the EntryView where I use that line of code...

Comment: Ohh its a variable declaration, did not see that, cant you move initialization to a function? if you cant you can always use nil coalescing operator and write `let myString = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.value(forKey: "myKey") as? String ?? ""` or declare `myString` as optional `let myString = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.value(forKey: "myKey") as? String`

Comment: thanks for help, I ll give it a try and see what crash analytics say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When force unwrapping with `!` you always run the risk of a crash if the value is nil (or with `as!` if the cast fails).

In this case, you can do this:

```
let myString:String = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.string(forKey: "myKey") ?? "Default value"
```

Using `string(forKey:)` avoids the need for the cast to `String` and then the nil coalescing `??` lets you provide a default value if none is found in the `UserDefaults`.

Comment: How can I do the same for Date instead of string?

Comment: let myDate:Date = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.value(forKey: "myDateWidget") as! Date

Comment: let myDate:Date = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.value(forKey: "myDateWidget") ?? Date()

Comment: `let myDate:Date = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx.xxx.widgetsharing")?.value(forKey: "myDateWidget") as? Date ?? Date()`